# Checking for a linear transformation when applied to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to linear algebra, and was asked to determine if the following is a linear transformation. What is throwing me off is that for the first time we are dealing with matrices instead of vectors, and I am not sure if what I and doing makes any sense. Any feedback would be very much appreciated!

$T:M_{n\times n}^{\Bbb R} \to M_{n\times n}^{\Bbb R}$ defined by $T(X) = X^2-X$

$M,N\in M_{n\times n}^{\Bbb R}$ will be two matrices subjected to the transformation, while $λ_1,λ_2$ are two scalars $ \in\Bbb R$.

$T(λ_1M+λ_2N)=λ_1M^2-λ_1M+λ_2N^2-λ_2N\\=λ_1(M^2-M)+λ_2(N^2-N)\\=λ_1Τ(M)+λ_2Τ(N)^2$

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get $$T(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)=λ_1M^2-λ_1M+λ_2N^2-λ_2N$$Shouldn't it be $$T(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)=(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)^2-(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)$$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri
As M transforms into $M^2-M$, I reasoned that $λ_1M$ would transform into $λ_1M^2-λ_1M$. Same thing for N. Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: Keep $X=\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N$. Thus, $$T(X)=X^2-X=(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)^2-(\lambda_1M+\lambda_2N)$$

Comment: you're right! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is no. A quick way to see this is using $1\times 1$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, arrays $[x]$. I make the identification $[x]=x$. Then, our map is $T(x)=x^2-x$ which is *not* linear. For instance, 
$$ T(1+1)=T(2)=2^2-2=2\ne 0+0=T(1)+T(1).$$
This mapping also fails to be linear in higher dimensional cases for the same reasons. For instance, try diagonal matrices in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, like 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$$